# Ruby on Rails config change while server is running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tarantula

Hi I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I have installed the Testia Tarantula application and am trying to read up on Ruby.

My question is how do I start/stop the server. 
For example: I want to change the Admin email, so I execute the following command to change the configuration of the app:
    RAILS_ENV=production rake db:config:app
But is this command ok to execute while the server is running, it has 'db' in the command which is what would warn me that I shouldn't run it while the server is up. Anyone have some helpful tips for learning Ruby on Rails server app management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Rails!

You can run rake db:xxxxx while the server is running and it won't hurt anything.  However I usually stop my server, run my rake command and then start it back up to ensure that all changes will be picked up.  If running in production, I would think you may want to restart the server just to make sure.  I believe that the schema is generated/updated upon server startup, just fyi.

As far as starting and stopping the server, if you are attached to it you can just use ctrl + c.  If it is detached, you can search for the pid and then kill -9 .

Answer (score 1):

Running rake db:anything will load rails on its own.  It doesn't matter if you have a server up or not.  This will happen in the background.  Think of it as the same as running a sql script while the server is running.  It's a separate process.